# While running stack.sh getting ""OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/'/home/rayra/.cache/pip/wheels... and exits

Tags: ubuntu, devstack

```
  >InsecurePlatformWarning
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 293, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 705, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 461, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 249, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 261, in link
    self._link = self._wheel_cache.cached_wheel(link, self.name)
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 63, in cached_wheel
    self._cache_dir, link, self._format_control, package_name)
  File "/home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tmp-venv-5XVD/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 124, in cached_wheel
    wheel_names = os.listdir(root)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/rayra/.cache/pip/wheels/99/e7/9a/68b1c8ca6f6f92b5feebd4d9434f50712b84f6a66d1285ea21'

+ exit_trap
+ local r=2
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ kill_spinner
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ [[ 2 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+ [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+ /home/rayra/devstack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2015-08-12-071442.txt for details
+ exit 2
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem today and it was solved after changing the owner of the`.cache` directory to my user.

Just run the following command:

```
$sudo chown rayra /home/rayra/.cache
```